# Redux state updates but component state not changing from first time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux, react-hooks

I am developing a login/register system using Redux,Hooks and Axios the action should fetch the backend and return a session to be updated in my reducer , after that I am trying to console.log(session) from my component the first time it is {} empty 'The initial state of session' is consoled the second time it is updated , I checked my redux state and everything works good and the state is updated from the first time so not a redux issue .The problem is in my component as I need it to wait for the Redux finishing and then console.log() , I tried to setTime() but it waits for the given time and after that It console the initial state {} again.

My code:

Component:
The problem is in the Redirect() function

```
import { LoginAction } from "../../Redux/Actions";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const Login = (props) => {
  let history = useHistory();
  const alert = useAlert();

  const { handleSubmit, register, errors } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    const userData = {
      username: data.username.toUpperCase(),
      password: data.password,
    };
    props.login(userData);
    setTimeout(1000, Redirect());
  };
  const Redirect = () => {
    if (props.session.user) {
      console.log(props.session);
      sessionStorage.setItem("storedSession", props.session.user.username);
      history.push("/dashboard");
    } else {
      alert.show(<div style={{ size: "10px" }}>{props.session.error}</div>);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="login">
      <div className="login-form">
        <h3 className="title">Sign In</h3>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter your username"
            name="username"
            id="username"
            ref={register({ required: true })}
          />
          {errors.username && errors.username.type === "required" && (
            <p className="error-before-submit">This is required</p>
          )}
          <input
            id="password"
            placeholder="Enter your password"
            name="password"
            type="password"
            ref={register({ required: true })}
          />
          {errors.password && errors.password.type === "required" && (
            <p className="error-before-submit">This is required</p>
          )}
          <input
            className="btn"
            type="submit"
            ref={register({ required: true })}
          />
          <a href="/register" className="register-link">
            Create an account
          </a>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  session: state.Session,
});
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  login: (user) => dispatch(LoginAction(user)),
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

Reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  Session: {},
};

const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case Register:
      return {
        ...state,
        Session: action.payload,
      };
    case Login:
      return {
        ...state,
        Session: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default rootReducer;
```

Action:

```
export function LoginAction(user) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    Axios.post(
      "/api/login",
      {
        username: user.username,
        password: user.password,
      },
      {
        headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" },
        withCredentials: true,
        crossdomain: true,
      }
    ).then((res) => {
      dispatch({
        type: Login,
        payload: res.data,
      });
    });
  };
}
```

How can I make my component take the updated state not the initial state FROM FIRST CLICK ??

Comment: you need to `redirect` after your `session` changes in `redux` ?

Comment: @SarthakAggarwal I need to redirect to the user's homepage if the session returned from redux is available and to alert the error if session returned is empty , but with this code the session changes after the first click but it is not redirecting from first time as the console.log(props.session) returns {} even if it is changed in the reducer state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage `useEffect` hook instead of using `timeout`

```
const {session} = props;

useEffect(()=>{ 

  Redirect()

},[session])
```

Comment: Glad to help @Hazem :)